# Как заменить одинаковые текстовые элементы в переменной на разные элементы из массива?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> создайте переменную равную "Квинтилий Вар потерял XX легионов в Германии: XXX, XXX, и XXX"
>   создайте массив с элементами  Legio XVII, Legio XVIII and Legio XIX
>   скомбинируйте все перменные чтобы получить "Квинтилий Вар потерял 3 легиона в Германии: Legio XIX, Legio XVII, и Legio XVIII"

Пытаюсь решить так, но со вторым элементом не выходит:

```
a = "Квинтилий Вар потерял XX легионов в Германии: XXX, XXX, и XXX"
b = ["Legio XVII", "Legio XVIII", "Legio XIX,"]
b.sort()
c = a.replace("XX легионов", "3 легиона").replace("XXX,", str(b[0])).replace("XXX", str(b[2])).replace(" и XXX", str(b[1]))
print(c)
```

Мой результат:

> Квинтилий Вар потерял 3 легиона в Германии: Legio XIX, Legio XIX, и Legio XVIII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
a = "Квинтилий Вар потерял XX легионов в Германии: XXX, XXX, и XXX"
b = ["Legio XVII", "Legio XVIII", "Legio XIX,"]
b.sort()
a.replace('XXX', '{}').replace('XX легионов', '{x2}').format(*b, x2="3 легиона")
```

Результат:

```
'Квинтилий Вар потерял 3 легиона в Германии: Legio XIX,, Legio XVII, и Legio XVIII'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
b = ["Legio XVII", "Legio XVIII", "Legio XIX"] 

res = a.replace("XXX", "{}").format(*sorted(b)).replace("XX", "3")
print(res)
>>> Квинтилий Вар потерял 3 легионов в Германии: Legio XIX, Legio XVII, и Legio XVIII
```